# Подключение внешней SDRAM к stm32 через FMC

Tags: c, stm32, ram

Имеется плата с микроконтроллером STM32F769II и микросхема SDRAM памяти MT48LC4M16A2, которая подключена через интерфейс FMC. Использую связку CubeMX и Keil uVision. Проблема заключается в том, что не работает код из стандартных примеров куба для данного миконтроллера (...\CubeMxRepository\STM32Cube_FW_F7_V1.15.0\Projects\STM32F769I_EVAL\Examples\FMC\FMC_SDRAM). Программа заключается в том, что на ОЗУ сначала записывается информация из одного буфера, а затем обратно считывается в другой буфер. В режиме отладки проверил, что инфа из одного буфера не оказывается в другом. Также проверил, что инициализация МК и периферии проходит без ошибок, и во время работы МК не глючит, не уходит в ошибку и так далее. Схема подключения ОЗУ к МК представлена ниже:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью мультиметра в режиме прозвонки проверил, что каждый пин МК подключен к соответствующему пину ОЗУ. Как можно проверить работу интерфейса, если с помощью логического анализатора это не получится сделать, т.к. частота тактирования в интерфейсе связи с ОЗУ 166 МГц, а частота выборки анализатора 24 МГц? В какую сторону необходимо копать для решения данной проблемы?

По совету в комментариях обратился на https://electronix.ru/forum/, где мне сказали, что с точки зрения электроники всё, может и не отлично, но пойдёт. Так что я полагаю дело именно в ПО. Ниже привёл функции инициализации FMC, инициализации внешней SDRAM. Быть может я просто не вижу ошибки. Частота ядра МК 200 МГц.

```
/* FMC initialization function */
static void MX_FMC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 0 */

  FMC_SDRAM_TimingTypeDef SdramTiming = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 1 */

  /** Perform the SDRAM1 memory initialization sequence
  */
  hsdram1.Instance = FMC_SDRAM_DEVICE;
  /* hsdram1.Init */
  hsdram1.Init.SDBank = FMC_SDRAM_BANK1;
  hsdram1.Init.ColumnBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_COLUMN_BITS_NUM_8;
  hsdram1.Init.RowBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_ROW_BITS_NUM_12;
  hsdram1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FMC_SDRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
  hsdram1.Init.InternalBankNumber = FMC_SDRAM_INTERN_BANKS_NUM_4;
  hsdram1.Init.CASLatency = FMC_SDRAM_CAS_LATENCY_3;
  hsdram1.Init.WriteProtection = FMC_SDRAM_WRITE_PROTECTION_DISABLE;
  hsdram1.Init.SDClockPeriod = FMC_SDRAM_CLOCK_PERIOD_2;
  hsdram1.Init.ReadBurst = FMC_SDRAM_RBURST_ENABLE;
  hsdram1.Init.ReadPipeDelay = FMC_SDRAM_RPIPE_DELAY_0;
  /* SdramTiming */
  SdramTiming.LoadToActiveDelay = 2;
  SdramTiming.ExitSelfRefreshDelay = 6;
  SdramTiming.SelfRefreshTime = 4;
  SdramTiming.RowCycleDelay = 6;
  SdramTiming.WriteRecoveryTime = 2;
  SdramTiming.RPDelay = 2;
  SdramTiming.RCDDelay = 2;

  if (HAL_SDRAM_Init(&hsdram1, &SdramTiming) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler( );
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 2 */
}
```

Последовательность команд по инициализации и настройки внешней sdram

```
static void SDRAM_Initialization_Sequence(SDRAM_HandleTypeDef *hsdram, FMC_SDRAM_CommandTypeDef *Command)
{
  __IO uint32_t tmpmrd =0;
  /* Step 1:  Configure a clock configuration enable command */
  Command->CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_CLK_ENABLE;
  Command->CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command->AutoRefreshNumber = 1;
  Command->ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  res=HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(hsdram, Command, 0xFFFF);

  /* Step 2: Insert 100 us minimum delay */
  /* Inserted delay is equal to 1 ms due to systick time base unit (ms) */
  HAL_Delay(1);

  /* Step 3: Configure a PALL (precharge all) command */
  Command->CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_PALL;
  Command->CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command->AutoRefreshNumber = 1;
  Command->ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  res=HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(hsdram, Command, 0xFFFF);

  /* Step 4 : Configure a Auto-Refresh command */
  Command->CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_AUTOREFRESH_MODE;
  Command->CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command->AutoRefreshNumber = 8;
  Command->ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  res=HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(hsdram, Command, 0xFFFF);
    HAL_Delay(1);
  /* Step 5: Program the external memory mode register */
  tmpmrd = (uint32_t)SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_1          |
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_SEQUENTIAL   |
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_3           |
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_OPERATING_MODE_STANDARD |
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_SINGLE;

  Command->CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_LOAD_MODE;
  Command->CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command->AutoRefreshNumber = 1;
  Command->ModeRegisterDefinition = tmpmrd;

  /* Send the command */
  res=HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(hsdram, Command, 0xFFFF);
    HAL_Delay(1);
  /* Step 6: Set the refresh rate counter */
  /* (15.62 us x Freq) - 20 */
  /* Set the device refresh counter */
  hsdram->Instance->SDRTR |= ((uint32_t)((1292)<< 1));
}
```

Непонятно в шестом шагу какую частоту надо вставлять в формулу, потому что в данном случае подставлено 166 МГц, т.е. частота на CLK, видимо. Но в примере для STM32F429I-Discovery вместо ((1292)<< 1) стоит (0x056A), что даёт нам частоту 90 МГц, т.е. частоту тактирования модуля FMC в микроконтролере.

Comment: Это сайт для программистов, вам лучше обратиться на https://electronix.ru/forum/

Comment: Туда я обращусь тоже, спасибо за совет, но вдруг здесь у меня проблема как раз таки в ПО.

Comment: Есть и раздел SO, посвящённый электронике.

Comment: А интерфейс FMC сам генерирует сигналы регенерации?

Comment: Каким образом это проверить?

Comment: @0andriy, генерирует, сейчас почитал про FMC, его смысл в том, чтобы в одно адресное пространство свести все виды памяти, sdram, spi и проч.

Comment: Ну начните с проверки сигналов Write Enable, Chip Select. Если с ними всё отлично, то смотрите, какой номер блока записывается по последовательному интерфейсу. (Я по схеме гадаю, спецификацию не читал)

Comment: Сигналов WE и CS с помощью логического анализатора (макс. 24 МГц) не увидел. Простым "ногодрыгом" удостоверился, что ножки МК в принципе живые. Во всех отладочных платах от STM для тактирования камня используется кварц на 25 МГц, я же использую 10 МГц, при этом скорректировав все делители и умножители так, чтобы тактирование ядра и FMC совпадало с примерами, но вдруг всё же мистическим образом это не правильно и можно использовать только 25 МГц?

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю для истории, чтобы кто-то мог меньше наступать на грабли:

SDRAM MT48LC4M32B2 на 150МГц
[image: STM32H7+MT48LC4M32B2]
4 слоя, разводка только на верхнем и нижнем, центральные слои - только питание и GND.
Разница в длине дорожек не более 22мм (минимальная 10мм, максимальная - 32мм)

Настройка взята остюда: https://narodstream.ru/stm-urok-62-fmc-sdram-chast-1/

[image: Настройка SDRAM в STM32CubeMX:]

```
#include "fmc.h"

#define SDRAM_BANK_ADDR                          ((uint32_t)0xC0000000)
#define SDRAM_TIMEOUT                            ((uint32_t)0xFFFF)

#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_1             ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_2             ((uint16_t)0x0001)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_4             ((uint16_t)0x0002)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_8             ((uint16_t)0x0003)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_SEQUENTIAL      ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_INTERLEAVED     ((uint16_t)0x0008)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_1              ((uint16_t)0x0010)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_2              ((uint16_t)0x0020)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_3              ((uint16_t)0x0030)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_OPERATING_MODE_STANDARD    ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_PROGRAMMED ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_SINGLE     ((uint16_t)0x0200)

void MX_SDRAM_InitEx(void)
{
    FMC_SDRAM_CommandTypeDef Command;
  __IO uint32_t tmpmrd = 0;
  HAL_StatusTypeDef res = HAL_OK;

  /* Step 1: Configure a clock configuration enable command */
  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_CLK_ENABLE;
  Command.CommandTarget          = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 1;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  res = HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);

  /* Step 2: Insert 100 us minimum delay */
  /* Inserted delay is equal to 1 ms due to systick time base unit (ms) */
  HAL_Delay(1);

  /* Step 3: Configure a PALL (precharge all) command */
  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_PALL;
  Command.CommandTarget          = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 1;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  res = HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);
  HAL_Delay(1);

  /* Step 4: Configure an Auto Refresh command */
  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_AUTOREFRESH_MODE;
  Command.CommandTarget          = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 8;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  res = HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);
  HAL_Delay(1);

  /* Step 5: Program the external memory mode register */
  tmpmrd = (uint32_t)SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_1          |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_SEQUENTIAL   |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_2           |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_OPERATING_MODE_STANDARD |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_SINGLE;

  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_LOAD_MODE;
  Command.CommandTarget          = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 1;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = tmpmrd;

  /* Send the command */
  res = HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);

  /* Step 6: Set the refresh rate counter */
  /* Set the device refresh rate */
  PLL1_ClocksTypeDef pll1_clocks;
  HAL_RCCEx_GetPLL1ClockFreq(&pll1_clocks);
  uint32_t frequency = pll1_clocks.PLL1_Q_Frequency/1000; // MHz to kH
  uint32_t refresh = frequency * 64 / 4096;               // Fq in Hz * refresh in ms / row count
  res = HAL_SDRAM_ProgramRefreshRate(&hsdram1, refresh );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ОЗУ в конечном итоге заработала. Подытожу здесь всё, что мне удалось наскрести по моей проблеме. На всякий случай приложил архив с файлами проекта. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tUCDr_n4Z-6gqN3d9Muiflo4f17oNd9r

1) Разводка печатной платы далека от идеала, но для частот работы SDRAM пойдёт. Так что, если вы столкнулись со схожей проблемой, и ваших знаний достаточно, чтобы утверждать, что на вашей плате разводка не хуже, то значит проблема точно не в ней.[image: верхний слой][image: первый средний слой][image: второй средний слой][image: нижний слой]

2) Включите и настройте модуль MPU. В примерах от ST он почему-то выключен, хотя в других примерах его всё же включают, и у меня без него тоже не работает.

3) Поставьте частоту работы тактирования ядра не более 200 МГц, т.к. максимальная частота работы FMC равна 100 МГц для МК STM32f769II при питающем напряжении 3.3 В. Если у вас другой МК от ST с модулем FMC, то поищите в даташите "maximum FMC_CLK =", чтобы узнать предельную частоту работы.

4)Я ещё поменял кварцевый резонатор с 10 МГц на 25 МГц, но думаю это роли не играет.

5)Была ещё проблема с неправильными настройками инициализации микросхемы памяти, так что внимательней читайте даташиты.